# Matlab - Unexpected Results from Differential Equation Solver Ode45

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation with the ode solver ode45 with MATLAB. I have tried using it with other simpler functions and let it plot the function. They all look correct, but when I plug in the function that I need to solve, it fails. The plot starts off at y(0) = 1 but starts decreasing at some point when it should have been an increasing function all the way up to its critical point.

```
function [xpts,soln] = diffsolver(p1x,p2x,p3x,p1rr,y0)
syms x y
yp = matlabFunction((p3x/p1x) - (p2x/p1x) * y); 
[xpts,soln] = ode45(yp,[0 p1rr],y0);
```

p1x, p2x, and p3x are polynomials and they are passed into this diffsolver function as parameters.

p1rr here is the critical point. The function should diverge after the critical point, so i want to integrate it up to that point.

EDIT: Here is the code that I have before using diffsolver, the above function. I do pade approximation to find the polynomials p1, p2, and p3. Then i find the critical point, which is the root of p1 that is closest to the target (target is specified by user).

I check if the critical point is empty (sometimes there might not be a critical point in some functions). If its not empty, then it uses the above function to solve the differential equation. Then it plots the x- and y- points returned from the above function basically.

```
function error = padeapprox(m,n,j)
global f df p1 p2 p3 N target

error = 0;
size = m + n + j + 2;

A = zeros(size,size);
for i = 1:m
    A((i + 1):size,i) = df(1:(size - i));
end
for i = (m + 1):(m + n + 1)
    A((i - m):size,i) = f(1:(size + 1 - i + m));
end
for i = (m + n + 2):size
    A(i - (m + n + 1),i) = -1;
end

if det(A) == 0
    error = 1;
    fprintf('Warning: Matrix is singular.\n');
end

V = -A\df(1:size); 

p1 = [1];
for i = 1:m
    p1 = [p1; V(i)];
end

p2 = [];
for i = (m + 1):(m + n + 1)
    p2 = [p2; V(i)];
end

p3 = [];
for i = (m + n + 2):size
    p3 = [p3; V(i)];
end

fx = poly2sym(f(end:-1:1)); 
dfx = poly2sym(df(end:-1:1));
p1x = poly2sym(p1(end:-1:1)); 
p2x = poly2sym(p2(end:-1:1)); 
p3x = poly2sym(p3(end:-1:1)); 
p3fullx = p1x * dfx + p2x * fx; 
p3full = sym2poly(p3fullx); p3full = p3full(end:-1:1); 

p1r = roots(p1(end:-1:1));
p1rr = findroots(p1r,target); % findroots eliminates unreal roots and chooses the one closest to the target

if ~isempty(p1rr)
    [xpts,soln] = diffsolver(p1x,p2x,p3fullx,p1rr,f(1));
    if rcond(A) >= 1e-10
        plot(xpts,soln); axis([0 p1rr 0 5]); hold all
    end
end
```

I saw some examples using another function to generate the differential equation but i've tried using the matlabFunction() method with other simpler functions and it seems like it works. Its just that when I try to solve this function, it fails. The solved values start becoming negative when they should all be positive.

I also tried using another solver, dsolve(). But it gives me an implicit solution all the time...

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is any way anyone can help you unless you provide runnable code. Also, are you sure that your critical point can be defined with respect to the independent variable (often this is time, but it may be something else in your case) of your system? I would think that it'd be defined with respect to the state variables, but I don't know what your system is.

Comment: @horchler, thanks for your reply. Sorry for not providing the code, but I wasn't sure what else is there to show actually... After using the diffsolver() function, i basically plot the x and y points returned from the function. When you said that I should check whether the critical point is defined, i actually have a line of code that checks whether the variable is empty, if that is what you meant...?

Comment: The code you added tells nothing and you should show how it fits in with first code (but it's probably not even relevant). This is question about numerical integration. What's inside of `diffsolver`?

Comment: @horchler, what i have about diffsolver is actually all of diffsolver... However, I added the code where I prep for diffsolver. I am actually doing pade approximations to find the polynomials p1, p2, and p3. The goal is to use these polynomials to find the original function, thats why I need to integrate the differential equation p1 * f' + p2 * f = p3. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since your code seems to work for simpler functions, you could try to increase the accuracy options of the ode45 solver.

This can be achieved by using *odeset*:

```
 options = odeset('RelTol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-10);
 [T,Y] = ode45(@function,[tspan],[y0],options);
```

Comment: thanks for your input! I added that code to it but it gave me warnings like this, 
Warning: Failure at t=2.217944e-01.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the
smallest value allowed (4.440892e-16) at time t. 

I should have mentioned that I also had these warnings even when I didn't add your suggested code...